# In Codeigniter framework, Php sessions are working only on localhost, but not on production server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using Codeigniter framework. Php sessions are working only on localhost and on the server.

What do I need to change?

Here is my

**config.php**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';

$config['sess_expiration']      = 3600;

$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;

$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;

$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';

$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;

$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3600;
```

Comment: Do you use a database to save your session? Provide us with some more info (config section about sessions)

Comment: Yes, please share your session configuration. Whatever you're trying to save sessions to isn't configured correctly on the server.

Comment: No i am not using DB to store the session. Please find above to see my config.php

Comment: Your config file is looking okay. Can you please share the code of controller where you use it.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter 2?

Comment: Take a look at your Cookie Related Variables in config.php `$config['cookie_domain']` and `$config['cookie_path']` in particular.

Comment: yes i am using CodeIgniter 2

Comment: sessions are working properly in localhost..not in server. I am using Php session $_SESSION to set the session.